# Loyalty program software/platform

Tags: web-apps

Wondering if someone can advice on an loyalty program web platform. I need something that allows collecting points, spending points on rewards, generates reports for admins etc

I'm interested in either an actual platform (developed, managed and hosted by 3rd party providers) or a piece of software that can be downloaded and installed on a server on your own. Paid, Open Source - doesn't matter.

I've done some google based research but instead of reading lines of marketing blurbs, would be great to know if anyone has an actual experiences working with one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: [Group FiO](https://www.groupfio.com/) We are also providing a [Loyalty management system software](https://www.groupfio.com/loyalty-management-system/) is a component of Group FiO’s [intelligent CRM](https://www.groupfio.com/intelligent-crm/), is a platform that intelligently manages your customer loyalty program including customer purchases and returns, points, rewards, and levels. What sets FiO’s LMP apart from other loyalty platform providers is its intelligence and closed-loop integration with Customer Data Platform, Customer Engagement Platform, and Customer Service Platform, allowing for smarter rewards and promotions delivered through the right channels at the right times. Simply having a loyalty program is no longer enough.

To build your base of returning customers along with their basket size and propensity for repeat business, it is essential that your loyalty platform is intelligent and integrated. Once that is achieved, all your basic processes can be automated which will innovate the way you interact with your loyalty customers.

Answer (score -1):

Disclosure: I’m from Antavo, a loyalty program provider and management platform.

The loyalty programs we’ve built from our clients include point systems, promotional campaigns with points, as well as gamified elements too, like membership tiers and rewarding non-purchase engagements.

We also have a dashboard which displays program performance metrics like enrollment in the program, point earn and spend, frequency of loyalty program actions (i.e. social sharing, friend referrals, video views) and the popularity of individual rewards.

https://antavo.com/